# App.js can't be saved to see changes made

Tags: javascript, expo

Using Expo and JavaScript to make an app. Got the software running and will load on my phone, however I am unable to save any changes made in the code scripts as it won't let me, just throws a general error and wants me to save as a separate file.

Does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to your rights on folder/files that you are trying to modify. If you are pc's administrator, then when you open your editor to change code just run it with administrator priviledge (right click -> run as administrator).

Comment: Which part? The software compiling, the software I edit the documents with or something else?

Comment: @Artyu the software you use to edit the documents